# How Does This Recursive Function Operate in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, output

I'd like to know how the 2nd output in the following code example is produced. How is the function able to count backwards after the if statement and recursive function call have ended?

```
void Recursion(int x)
{
    if(x < 4) {
        cout << x << " "; // 1st output: 1 2 3
        Recursion(x + 1); 
    }

    cout << x << " "; // 2nd output: 4 3 2 1
}

int main()
{
    Recursion(1);
}
```

Comment: What happens after any function call?  When the function returns, execution continues on the next line after the call.

Comment: do you have debugger? just use it to step over every line to see what happen

Comment: use a debugger to understand how recursion works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to interpret the question as "how can the function remember what it was doing when it returns?".

The C++ standard doesn't say (IIRC it's left to implementations to find a solution that works). In practice, though, the answer is "the stack".

In computer science generally, a stack is a last-in-first-out data structure. Push the sequence 1, 2 then 3 into a stack then do three pops and you get 3, 2 then 1.

In the early days, programming languages often didn't support recursive or re-entrant calls. Each function/procedure had a little block of memory it owned where it stored its parameters, local variables and which function to return to after completion. If you tried to call a function that was already running, that would mean storing two sets of local variables and two return addresses in the space for one, so that was an error.

However, one of the innovations in IIRC the Algol programming language was support for recursion. And at around the same time, "processor stacks" were becoming a thing.

A processor stack (among other things) allows you to use a different method for handling parameters, local variables and return addresses. You don't need a permanently allocated block for each function - you allocate a block (at the top of the stack) when you call the function. The location of the current "stack frame" is relative to the current "stack pointer". And this means you can have multiple stack frames for the same function on the stack at the same time.

So calling a function involves creating a new stack frame at the top of the stack, and adjusting the stack pointer to suit. And returning from a function involves discarding that stack frame and adjusting the stack pointer back, so the top stack frame is now the stack frame for the caller. That caller may or may not have been the same function - it doesn't matter because each call got it's own stack frame storing a separate set of parameters, local variables, a separate return address etc.

So just before the `Recursion (3)` call, the stack would look something like...

```
|-------------------+-------------------+
| Recursion Frame 1 | Recursion Frame 2 |
|---------------+---+---------------+---+
| ???           | X | ???           | X |
|---------------+---+---------------+---+
| ???           | 1 | ???           | 2 |
|---------------+---+---------------+---+
                                        ^
                                        |
                                      STACK
                                     POINTER
```

The `???` represents "housekeeping" stuff like the return address.

Comment: Very informative answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Think about just the first call to Recursion.

The function is going to print a "1", then other stuff is going to happen, then it prints a "1" again.

So the output is going to be `1 ... 1`

Now think about the second call to Recursion, its going to print a "2", then other stuff is going to happen, then it prints a "2" again.

So its output is `2 ... 2`.

Stick those two together and you get `1 2 ... 2 1`

And then just keep going.

Answer (score 1):

You should try stepping through the code, executing it with pencil and paper (or a virtual scratch pad). Let's keep the function definition close:

```
void Recursion(int x)
{
1    if(x < 4) {
2        cout << x << " "; // 1st output: 1 2 3
3        Recursion(x + 1); 
.    }
. 
4    cout << x << " "; // 2nd output: 4 3 2 1
5    return;
}
```

Now, let's call `main`:

```
call main
    call Recursion(1)    -> x := 1
        (1) if (x < 4)   -> true
            (2) cout << x << " ";                                  // with x == 1
            (3) call Recursion(x + 1)    -> x := 2
                (1) if (x < 4)           -> true
                    (2) cout << x << " ";                          // with x == 2
                    (3) call Recursion(x + 1)    -> x := 3
                        (1) if (x < 4)           -> true
                            (2) cout << x << " ";                  // with x == 3
                            (3) call Recursion(x + 1)    -> x := 4
                                (1) if (x < 4)           -> false
                                (4) cout << x << " ";              // with x == 4
                            (5) end Recursion            -> x:= 3
                        (4) cout << x << " ";                      // with x == 3
                    (5) end Recursion            -> x:= 2
                (4) cout << x << " ";                              // with x == 2
            (5) end Recursion            -> x:= 1
        (4) cout << x << " ";                                      // with x == 1
    (5) end Recursion            -> del x
end main
```

And now, you can just check what is outputed: `cout << x << " ";` is called successively with values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, yielding `"1 2 3 4 3 2 1 "`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you look at this:

```
string RecursiveReturn(int x)
{
    if(x >= 4) {
        return to_string(x);
    }

    return to_string(x) + " " + RecursiveReturn(x+1) + " " + to_string(x);
}

int main()
{
    cout << Recursion(1);
}
```

A recursive call is like any other function call... it is evaluated, and when it returns the calling function continues.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The stack depicts that when "1st output" is performed to stdout, the "2nd output" is inserted into stack("function stack").

When the function "recursion" returns to "main" function the unwinding or popping contents of stack happens. If you visulaise properly this is how it gives output.

Comment: Great visualization of the stack. Thank you for your answer.